# Uncaught Error: Both UserPoolId and ClientId are required

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

i'm working on amplify auth to signin with cognito in vue js apps, following is the code i've added in main.js:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
Amplify.configure({
      Auth: {
        mandatorySignIn: false,
        region: config.cognito.REGION,
        userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
        UserPoolClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID,
      },
    });
```

but somehow i'm receive this kind of error:

```
CognitoUserPool.js?17a7:46 Uncaught Error: Both UserPoolId and ClientId are required.
    at new CognitoUserPool (CognitoUserPool.js?17a7:46)
    at AuthClass.configure (Auth.js?bf82:183)
    at eval (Amplify.js?7d03:83)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at AmplifyClass.configure (Amplify.js?7d03:82)
    at eval (main.js?56d7:15)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1692)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:2809)
```

i've tried many ways following the reference video and aws amplify documentation. but still same error still occured and my page is blank with the error in console.
checked the Auth option and all was good and right. how do i overcome this error? i'm also not using any client secret hash as js sdk not worked with app client with secret hash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The config parameter names need to be

```
...
userPoolId: '...'
userPoolWebClientId: '...'
...
```

as defined here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/a047ce73abe98c3bf82e888c3afb4d2f911805f3/packages/auth/src/types/Auth.ts#L40